# Rotating a Polygon After Rotating a Background image

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, rotations

I'm trying to solve a coordinate transformation problem I'm having a hard time figuring out.

For context, I have an image, and on top of it I draw a polygon. (On the figure below you can assume the image is the gray and red shape, and the polygon is the cyan shape).

The image as a whole is rotated, so now the polygon does not match the position relative to the new rotated image.

My question is: how can I transform the points of the polygon so that they match the position relative to the new image coordinate system?

I have tried rotating the polygon 90 degrees relative to its centroid, but that gives me a polygon that has a bit of an offset from the position where it should be.

Here's a figure to describe the idea:

[Example figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvkUl.png)

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Did you try rotating both the background and the polygon about the same point?

Comment: I tried rotating the polygon from the 0,0 point. But I'm not sure if the image rotation is performed in the same way since I'm getting that from an external system.

Comment: No, you should rotate the background and the polygon about the same point by the same angle.  Then all relative positions of the polygon with respect to the background will be preserved.

Comment: I see, then what I need to understand is: if I'm rotating an image so that it's width is now it's height and vice versa. (Imagine a phone that change from portrait to landscape). I this rotation a rotation from the center of the image? I know the angle is 90 degrees. But I'm having a hard time figuring out the point

Comment: Yes.  The rotation for the both the background and the polygon is about the center of the background (which is a rectangle).